# Re-sizing image resizes entire nav-bar & links

Tags: html, css, image, resize, navbar

1. I'm writing simple HTML & CSS & JS code,

   ```
   I've trying to create a responsive nav-bar with my logo as a link for the home page - however,
   when the navbar height is ideal (at 2-3rem) the image is far too small,
   ```

   I've tried adjusting the padding and margins but I can not enlarge
   the image without enlarging the rest of my assets in the nav-bar.

   [2rem nav-bar with small image][1] [HTML Code][2] [CSS Code][3]
   [Image at ideal size, links & nav bar too big][4]

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nnBc.png   [2]:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBgbj.png   [3]:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkcrj.png   [4]:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUj7m.png

   Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask] and [mre] and post the actual code (not images) so that we can better assist you :)

Comment: Please add your html and css on your post so that we can copy paste and save our time.

Comment: If you are putting the image in as a background, investigage background-size: cover or background-size: contain. If you are putting it in as an img element then you can look into object-fit instead.

Answer (score 0):

make your nav-bar like this: `.nav-bar:min-height:10vh;` before this make sure to remove all the padding and margin and set the box-sizing to border box: `*{margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;}`

Comment: let us see your code: to answer specifically